# ¿Es necesario u obligatorio poner la fuente de una respuesta basada de SOen o cualquier otro lugar?

Tags: soporte

Mi pregunta es esa, muchas veces veo que usuarios responden a preguntas de otros de las siguientes maneras:

- Prácticamente copian y pegan respuestas del SOen u otros sitios y se quedan casi que
  con toda la autoría sin citar la fuente original de la respuesta o darle créditos a la misma.
- Otros por su parte, basan o copian y pegan su respuesta del SOen u otros sitios pero aún así citan sus respectivas fuentes.

Me reservo el derecho de publicar ejemplos para no generar controversia en la comunidad.

Quisiera saber, más que todo por ética con la comunidad de StackExchange y/o demás sitios relacionados a responder dudas como estas.

Comment: Considero que mas que necesario u obligatorio, sería _éticamente correcto_ agregar la fuente de una respuesta. Tu pregunta me resulta familiar a otra pregunta realizada en el meta de SOes relacionada con las preguntas y respuestas publicadas en el sitio en inglés y traducidas aquí. No tengo el enlace a la mano, pero la respuesta aceptada indica que la respuesta debe contener un enlace a la fuente original. Desconozco si esto es algo que se pueda _reglamentar_ pero si se puede _motivar / encourage_ a los usuarios.

Comment: @Mauricio te refieres a [esta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/679/dar-como-respuesta-a-una-pregunta-un-enlace-a-so-ingles-es-v%C3%A1lido)?

Comment: @JuankGlezz esa es. Gracias :).

Comment: Conozco estos casos. Cuando los veas, repórtalos para atención de moderación, indicando la posible fuente de origen de la publicación. He visto en SOen que este tipo de publicaciones son eliminadas directamente por los moderadores. Plagiar es malo y punto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De no citar la fuente *se podría* incurrir en [plagio](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagio) y en el caso particular de lo publicado en la red de sitios de Stack Exchange se falta a la licencia con la que se publica el contenido.

Nótese que al pie de esta página se muestra algo como lo siguiente (tomado el día de hoy):

[image: Pie de página de Meta Stack Overflow en español]

Referencia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 2):

Lo más recomendable es que se cite la fuente, pues siempre es importante atribuirle al autor el crédito.

Ahora bien, dependiendo del sitio de donde se saque la información, pueden haber diferentes formas de derechos de autor, desde la prohibición parcial o total del sitio, hasta el poder copiar cualquier fragmento, sin necesidad de hacer una referencia al autor.

También se debe de recordar que muchas veces, al querer responder una pregunta, una persona tenga un punto de vista muy parecido al de otra persona, o exista una forma estándar y optimizada, que pueda aparecer en varios sitios, pero que la persona que responda la pregunta también la sepa.

Para finalizar, creo que sí se debe de citar la fuente, pues esto ayuda a dar a conocer otros sitios de ayuda, foros, wikis...